# Calculating Fermi energy of free electron gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

I want to know if I'm understanding this right. I'm told to find the Fermi energy for a 2-D infinite square well of size $a$ (in both directions) with $N$ non-interacting particles using a Fermi circle.

My interpretation is this: the Fermi energy for an electron gas is simply the energy difference between the highest and lowest energy states. A 2-D Fermi circle has radius $\pi/a$. So now I just need to find the lowest possible energy state and the highest possible energy state and subtract the two, but because we are dealing with an electron gas I can take the lowest energy state to be zero kinetic energy. So I simply need to find the highest energy state. Is this correct?

Comment: It is the difference in energy between the lowest and highest occupied state at zero temperature.

Comment: Any hints on how to find the highest occupied state?

Comment: presumably you would find the energy levels for your potential, fit two fermions in each level starting at the bottom until you have exhausted your $N$ fermions...

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352293328_Perfect_Quantum_gas_in_n-dimensions
This article may be useful for you